# App access token destroys user access token and disconnect user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

All over my facebook app i'm user the: api('me/something')
to query the graph, all was fine untill i got to the friends ranking.

I wanted to get all users friends that uses the app.
As i found a way doing that with app_id, like that:

```
    $facebook->api($this->app_id .'/scores/');
```

this code is inside some controller and i'm loading it with jquery ajax request,
when i do that, the data i want works, i get the friend. BUT,
when i refreshing the page, exactly after that, i got the error:

```
An active access token must be used to query information about the current user
```

By refreshing again, and everything is good again, 
Thanks alot for who can help.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved,i just called the $facebook->api->('me') somewhere before instantiate the user.